# Linking both 32bit and 64bit .so files with g++ for a c++ program

Tags: c++, g++, 64-bit

I am trying to link both 32bit and 64bit .so files at the same time for a c++ program.
I am using 64bit Ubuntu 12.04.1 I also don't have the source files to recompile.

When I run the g++ command:

```
g++ onlineTraining.cpp -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/extern/include/ -L /home/forest/SoarSuite/out/ -L /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86/ -I /home/forest/SoarSuite/out/include -leng -lmat -lmex -lut -lSoar
```

I get the following output since it doesn't recognize the 32bit .so files:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86//libeng.so when searching for -leng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86//libmat.so when searching for -lmat
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmat
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86//libmex.so when searching for -lmex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmex
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86//libut.so when searching for -lut
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lut
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I run the g++ command with -m32:

```
g++ -m32 onlineTraining.cpp -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/extern/include/ -L /home/forest/SoarSuite/out/ -L /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a_Student/bin/glnx86/ -I /home/forest/SoarSuite/out/include -leng -lmat -lmex -lut -lSoar
```

I get the following output since now it doesn't recognize 64bit .so files:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/forest/SoarSuite/out//libSoar.so when searching for -lSoar
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSoar
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is it possible to link both of the 34bit and 64bit .so files at the same time?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @user93353 I am using a C++ program to interface between Matlab and a cognitive architecture called SOAR. I don't really have a choice in doing this on my computer since I only have the 32 bit binaries for Matlab and the 64bit binaries for SOAR and I don't have the source files to recompile them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. 32-bit libraries can only be linked into a 32-bit executable, and 64-bit libraries can only be linked into a 64-bit executable.

If the Matlab libraries you are trying to link in are only available as 32-bit, you will need to build your application as 32-bit (using `-m32`) as well, and link in only 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of that. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest making a shell script or make file that runs the two compiler commands.

Comment: The problem is described in the question as "trying to link as 32bit fails AND trying to link as 64bit fails", your suggested solution is "do both". How does that help?

Comment: @us2012 I answered the OP's explicit question, which asks how to link 32- and 64-bit versions of some code. Of course after looking more closely at the output, I can see that the real question should be why does linking fail in both cases.

Comment: What the OP asked explicitly is, I quote, "Is it possible to link both of the 34bit and 64bit .so files at the same time?". There is nothing unclear about that, and making shell scripts or make files has nothing to do with either the question or the solution.

Comment: @us2012 And my answer states exactly how to link both with a single command. The OP doesn't ask anything about why his current method fails (which is certainly the real issue). So you are right that my answer doesn't address the real problem. The question doesn't even address the real problem.